# Other alternatives of column command

Tags: shell-script, awk, columns

I have a file and I need to extract two columns.

However, I can't align it properly. I tried to use `column -t` but I am receiving the error message `bash: column: command not found`.

```
awk '{print $1" "$2}' | column -t
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWK can align its output on its own, if you print separate output fields and use a tab as the output field separator:

```
echo a b | awk -vOFS='\t' '{ print $1, $2 }'
```

You can get the same effect for any number of fields by getting AWK to rebuild `$0`:

```
echo a b c d | awk -vOFS='\t' 'NF > 0 { $1 = $1 } 1'
```

Check out AWK's `printf` function if you want more sophisticated output.

Comment: how will this work if the number of columns vary? sometimes there will be 5 columns, sometimes, 7, etc.

Comment: Voted up for going beyond the scope of the original question! @nerf123, you should edit your question to include all the information someone answering would need.